# Ellipse not properly scaling and rotating in pgfplot axis environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, scaling

I'm having trouble drawing an ellipse in a pgfplots `axis` environment based on the major axes, minor axes, and angle w.r.t. the x-axis. I've managed to draw such an ellipse using Tikz, however, the rotation of the angle does not properly respect the aspect ratio between the axis. What I mean by this is that if, for a figure with fixed width and height, with equal aspect ratio, the angle is 45°, then increasing the range of the x-axis should "squish" the elipse (and increase the angle). So, how do I rotate ellipse w.r.t. the coordinate system itself, not just "the screen"? Thanks!

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        name=plot_left,
        scale only axis,
        height=35mm,
        width=15mm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=3,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
    ]
        \draw[draw=blue] (axis cs:1,1) ellipse [x radius=0.25, y radius=0.5, rotate=45];
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis} [
        name=plot_right,
        at={(plot_left.north east)},
        anchor=north west,
        xshift=10mm,
        scale only axis,
        height=35mm,
        width=90mm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=3,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
    ]
        \draw[draw=blue] (axis cs:1,1) ellipse [x radius=0.25, y radius=0.5, rotate=45];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: ellipse]

**Desired:**

To clarify, this is what I am looking for: so something along the lines of Jasper Habicht's solution `(axis cs:1,1) ellipse [x radius=0.25*\a, y radius=0.5*\b, rotate=45*\c]`, where `\a`, `\b` and `\c` are calculated based on the aspect ratio and image width.

[image: desired]

Comment: Hi!  Are you sure you want to put together `height=35mm` with `xmin` and `xmax`?  You are "composing" coordinate transformations.  And maybe you should add a code line about the pgf version, something like `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}`.  This will show you that the coordinates count when mixing `axis` and `\draw`.  By the way, why do you need `pgfplots`?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for the tip: `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}` was indeed missing. As to your other two comments: yes, I do need both `height`, `width`, `xmin` and `xmax` because I'm both constrained by layout and some region of R^2 I want to plot. I also need `pgfplots` because there's a lot more in the graph than just the ellipse (i.e. trajectories loaded from a .csv file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured it out thanks to Jasper Habicht's suggestion, as well as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2645689/what-is-the-parametric-equation-of-a-rotated-ellipse-given-the-angle-of-rotatio) post: turns out it's really not as complicated as I thought.

So, with the code below, you can plot an ellipse in a `pgfplots` axis environment having specified the center x, y and the major, minor and angle w.r.t. the x-axis.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\newcommand{\addellipse}[5]{\addplot [domain=0:360, samples=50, draw=blue] ({(#3/2)*cos(x)*cos(#5) - (#4/2)*sin(x)*sin(#5) + #1}, {(#3/2)*cos(x)*sin(#5) + (#4/2)*sin(x)*cos(#5) + #2});}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        name=plot_left,
        scale only axis,
        height=35mm,
        width=15mm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=3,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
    ]
        \addellipse{1}{1}{1}{0.5}{45}
        );
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis} [
        name=plot_right,
        at={(plot_left.north east)},
        anchor=north west,
        xshift=10mm,
        scale only axis,
        height=35mm,
        width=90mm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=3,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
    ]
        \addellipse{1}{1}{1}{0.5}{45}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**Output:**

[image: proper_scaling]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether this is what you mean, but you can calculate the angle of rotation by dividing the width and height through the axis units and then get the arctan, but I am unsure whether this will really result the correct output actually:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        name=plot_left,
        scale only axis,
        height=35mm,
        width=15mm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=3,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
    ]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{
            atan(
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}))/
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/height}/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})))
        }
        \draw[draw=blue] (1,1) ellipse [x radius=0.25, y radius=0.5, rotate=\a];
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis} [
        name=plot_right,
        at={(plot_left.north east)},
        anchor=north west,
        xshift=10mm,
        scale only axis,
        height=35mm,
        width=90mm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=3,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
    ]
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{
            atan(
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/width}/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}))/
                (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/height}/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax}-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})))
        }
        \draw[draw=blue] (1,1) ellipse [x radius=0.25, y radius=0.5, rotate=\a];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

The best way is probably to somehow calculate the parametric function of the ellipsis and plot it. This would be something like this:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis} [
        name=plot_left,
        scale only axis,
        height=35mm,
        width=15mm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=3,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
    ]
        \addplot[domain=0:360, samples=200, blue](
            {cos(x)*sqrt(0.33/(sin(2*x)+2))+1},
            {sin(x)*sqrt(0.33/(sin(2*x)+2))+1}
        );
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis} [
        name=plot_right,
        at={(plot_left.north east)},
        anchor=north west,
        xshift=10mm,
        scale only axis,
        height=35mm,
        width=90mm,
        xmin=0,
        xmax=3,
        ymin=0,
        ymax=2,
    ]
        \addplot[domain=0:360, samples=200, blue](
            {cos(x)*sqrt(0.33/(sin(2*x)+2))+1},
            {sin(x)*sqrt(0.33/(sin(2*x)+2))+1}
        );
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jasper, thanks for the solution! This is indeed in the direction of my desired solution, although now the scaling seems off? I've edited my question to further clarify, thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I made a silly mistake. It should be arctan of course, since tan(45) = 1. The radii should scale correctly already, I think.

Comment: Actually, I am at a loss currently ... I need to think about this.

Comment: Yeah, I haven't managed to make any headway either. Since I don't actually know how to convert my major, minor, and angle formulation into a parametric variant... but thanks for the answer!